# openGL single channel texture always samples 0

Tags: c++, opengl, alpha

I'm trying to render font on screen using freetype. For that, I implemented single channel texture but it always samples 0.

cpp

```
unsigned char *blankData = new unsigned char[8 * 8];
for(int i = 0; i < 8 * 8; i++){
    blankData[i] = 126;
}
    
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);

glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

GLuint m_texture2D;
glGenTextures(1, &m_texture2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture2D);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, 8, 8, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, blankData);

glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(m_program, "texture2D"), 0);

checkGLError();
```

`glGetError()` returns `GL_NO_ERROR`

fragment Shader

```
#version 330 core

in vec2 texCoord;
in vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D texture2D;
out vec4 outColor;


void main()
{
    vec4 texColor = texture(texture2D, texCoord);
    outColor = vec4(texColor.r, texColor.r, texColor.r, 1.0f);

}
```

result
[image]

ff00ff: clear color

black: fragment shader output texcoord bottomLeft(0, 0) to topRight(1, 1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not generating [mipmaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap) (with [`glGenerateMipmap`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenerateMipmap.xhtml)) it is important to set `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER`. Since the default filter is `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR`, the texture would be "Mipmap Incomplete" if you do not change the minimize function to `GL_NEAREST` or `GL_LINEAR`.

```py
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture2D);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```